# Dashed line is painted incorrectly on a meta file canvas

Tags: delphi, gdi+

I had a code which draws the diagrams on a canvas using GDI+ on a bitmap canvas. The bitmap was converted to PNG and exported to an external service/user. But there is obviously scaling problem with PNG, so I thought why not drawing to an enhanced metafile and then export in emf. So I adjusted the code and almost eveything is perfect (texts, normal lines, etc) but there is one issue: dashed lines looks super garbage! Does not matter what pen width is set (0.5 or 1) they are always thick and small gaps between dashes. I tried custom dash style pattern - it looked better but still very thick line:

[image]

The following code produces the EMF above:

```
  Result := TMetaFile.Create;
  try
    var LMetaCanvas := TMetafileCanvas.Create(Result, 0);
    try
      G := TGPGraphics.Create(LMetaCanvas.Handle);
      G.CompositingQuality := CompositingQualityHighQuality;
      G.TextRenderingHint := TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit;
      G.SmoothingMode := SmoothingModeAntiAlias;

      var LPen: IGPPen := TGPPen.Create(TGPColor.Red, 1);
      G.DrawLine(LPen, 100, 0, 0, 100);

      LPen := TGPPen.Create(TGPColor.Black, 1);
      LPen.DashStyle := TGPDashStyle.DashStyleDash;
      G.DrawLine(LPen, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    finally
      LMetaCanvas.Free;
    end;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
```

I searched the web about this problem, but nothing useful found so far. I hope for your help dear colleagues.